# How to add own tags into the wordpress first level menu list?

Tags: html, wordpress

Here is my structure:

```
<ul class="no-list">
 <li>
<a href="#">
  <strong>
    <img src="HERE/PATH/TO/MY/IMAGE" alt="">
  </strong>
  <span>First Level Menu</span>
</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to insert in first level some image, and add alternate style for span tag.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may find these docs useful to get you started and then can come back with a more detailed code related question: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter hook `nav_menu_item_title` for that:

```
// add this to your functions.php
add_filter('nav_menu_item_title', 'my_nav_menu_item_title', 10, 4);
function my_nav_menu_item_title( $title, $item, $args, $depth ) {

    if ( $depth == 0 ) {
        // first level
        $title = '<strong><img src="HERE/PATH/TO/MY/IMAGE" alt=""></strong><span>' . $title . '</span>';
    }

    return $title;

}
```